# Does material-ui have a date-picker?

Tags: material-ui

I installed material-ui "^1.0.0-beta.36". The documentation says there's date-picker.

But I can't find it in `node_modules\material-ui` , nor in any of the subfolders.

The change log suggests that a datepicker is planned to be supported in future releases:

> 1.0.0-beta.17 - *Oct 16, 2017*
>
> As this garbage collection stabilize, we will be able to add new
>   features, like a stepper, extension panel or date/time pickers. But we
>   are not here yet.

Answer (score 1):

Material-ui v1 currently provides several date pickers. However, there's no specific `DatePicker` component.

Instead, you use the `type` prop of the `TextField` component to specify that you want a date picker rather than your typical text input. Here's an example that will give you a classic date picker:

```
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

<TextField
  type="date"
  defaultValue="2017-05-24"
/>
```

There are also other pickers with more than just the date. For example:

- Time Picker: `type="time"`
- Date and Time Picker: `type="datetime-local"`

You can find more information about this on the [pickers page of the docs](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/pickers/).

Answer (score 0):

```
  import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

  <TextField
    id="date"
    label="Birthday"
    type="date"
    defaultValue="2017-05-24"
    className={classes.textField}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI npm package in itself only supports the native Date picker like this:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

<TextField
   type="date"
/>
```

However there is a Material-UI supported and compatible npm package you can install with:

```
npm i @material-ui/pickers
```

And then in your code:

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';

// pick a date util library
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import LuxonUtils from '@date-io/luxon';

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Root />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Example copy pasted from the official documentation at https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation